# Facebook 2200 callback verification failed

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to subscribe to `picture` object of a specific Facebook page. In order to do that I am following this [article](http://alexandernorway.blogspot.com/2012/08/facebook-real-time-api-tutorial.html). I made uploaded the PHP file that would serve as callback [here](http://www.shameemcompany.com/facebook.php). Code below:

```
<?php                                    
/**
 * This is sample subscription endpoint for using Facebook real-time update
 * See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime to additional
 * documentation
 */

// Please make sure to REPLACE the value of VERIFY_TOKEN 'abc' with 
// your own secret string. This is the value to pass to Facebook 
//  when add/modify this subscription.
define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'app_code_123');                                    
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];                             

// In PHP, dots and spaces in query parameter names are converted to 
// underscores automatically. So we need to check "hub_mode" instead
//  of "hub.mode".                                                      
if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' &&       
    $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
  echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} else if ($method == 'POST') {                                   
  $updates = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); 
  // Replace with your own code here to handle the update 
  // Note the request must complete within 15 seconds.
  // Otherwise Facebook server will consider it a timeout and 
  // resend the push notification again.
  error_log('updates = ' . print_r($updates, true));              
}
?>
```

Then I got my `access_token` as directed in the article where I replaced `client_id` with `APP_ID` and `client_secret` with `APP SECRET` from my app details: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<REMOVED APP ID>&client_secret=<REMOVED CLIENT SECRET>`

Followed by an attempt to create the subscription:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<REMOVED APP ID>/subscriptions?access_token=<REMOVED APP ACCESS TOKEN>object=user&fields=feed&verify_token=app_code_123&method=post&callback_url=http://www.shameemcompany.com/facebook.php`

But it fails with the error:

```
"message": "(#2200) callback verification failed: ",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2200
```

I want to subscribe to a specific Facebook page so where or how would I specify that?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)? Is your callback definitely responding with the `hub.challenge` when Facebook makes the verification request to your callback URL?

Comment: @Igy I don't know. I followed the tutorial exactly. Did not mention anything regarding the `hub.challenge`. How would I determine if it was or not?

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the part marked 'Subscription Verification': Did you verify that this part happened correctly?

Comment: @Igy That is what I want to know that how I would verify that my callback handled the verification correctly. Since, I could not find any clue I followed a tutorial. Could you please breakdown what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

First you must use HTTP POST method instead of sending "..&method=POST&.."

Second, your server must be reachable from the internet.

And third, your server must be able to process concurrent requests, because facebook sends verification requests simultaneously.